# Why does my app stop working when I switch the place of elements?

Tags: android, xml

[image]I'm writing a simple application which sets "yes" to such a TextView *(its value is "no" by default)* when I click on a button *(the Button is next to the TextView)*. All fine .. It works perfectly.

So **what's the problem?** When I close the program and then switch the place of them *(both the button and the TextView)* in the layout *(by dragging)*, then surprisingly the app doesn't work anymore. Noted that when I switch the place of them again *(like the first time)*, it works as well.

Can please anyone explain my why my app stops working when I switch the place of those two elements?

**Working XML codes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Won't work version:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java codes:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FirstAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button   btn;
    TextView txt;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                txt.setText("yes");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I try the same codes and operation on Android Studio. And get the errors below Which shows **java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dysaniazzz.testdemo, PID: 30870
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dysaniazzz.testdemo/com.example.dysaniazzz.testdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1219)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5032)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at com.example.dysaniazzz.testdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5310)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2179)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1219)?
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)?
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)?
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5032)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)?
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)?
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)?
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)?
```

Comment: Post your full stack trace

Comment: @GabeSechan What do you mean "full stack trace" ?

Comment: When you crash (which is what happens when you see that Unfortunately... screen), a stack trace saying what the problem was and where it was is printed to the log.  You use that to debug your problems.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see. Just how can I access the stack trace in Eclips?

Comment: It should be in the debug tab somewhere.  Or use adb logcat from the command line.

Comment: Please read this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks.

Comment: @GabeSechan I did .. may you plesae take a look at it?

Comment: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button  You're trying to cast your text view as a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch the order without regenerating `R.java`, you get misleading errors because your view IDs have not been reassigned.

You must Clean & Rebuild the project. I believe Android Studio / Gradle regenerates the resources for every build, Eclipse mostly just compiles the Java code.

Comment: Can I regenerating R.java without clean layout ? How ?

Comment: I went in R.java file and remove IDs and ctrl+s to save. An error occure and IDs returns and **all problems gone** and its works . Thanks for your useful helps.

Comment: @MostafaUTD In this case, you have to mark this answer as accepted one .. also you can give it an upvote `;-)`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, That error say the same thing and discard my manual changes. After that "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" gone!

Answer (score 0):

I basically just create a new xml file when this occurs. Sometimes rebuilding doesn't work as it is supposed to. So try creating a new xml file with the layout that you want, then you clean and rebuild.

Comment: Yes, It can be last method.